# VB.Net Dropdownlist Help

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I am trying to figure out how to do this code example below

Backend..
         I have sql 2008r2 database and have a couple tables basically in my page load event of the vb project i am calling a select statement such as

```
        Dim strQuery As String = "Select * from RoomName_List"
        Dim con As New SqlConnection(strConnString)
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.CommandText = strQuery
        cmd.Connection = con

        Try
            con.Open()
            ddlRoomName.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            ddlRoomName.DataTextField = "RoomName"
            ddlRoomName.DataValueField = "intRoom"
            ddlRoomName.DataBind()
```

defaultpage i have a cmd click event
 `Session("intRoom") = ddlRoomName.Text`

Then what i am doing is sending the values to a session variable and redirecting to another page.

Here is where the problem is when i call my session variable and it displays on the confirmation page it is displaying the dropdownlist value.

Which i would like to submit that value to my database table but would like to actually display the datatextfield is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Its difficult to understand your question, do you want to get Selectedvalue of Dropdown,   intRoom?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the Text instead of the Value.  You could use your stored Session variable to achieve this.

```
Label1.Text = ddlRoomName.Items.FindByValue(Session["intRoom"].ToString()).Text;
```